# Win32 - How do I catch key event in background, without using global key hook or RegisterHotKey?

Tags: winapi

I made a program that takes a screenshot of a game window when a specific key is pressed. I am using `RegisterHotKey()`. It works well, but there is a problem: when the game window is on focus, my program can't receive that key event. To take a screenshot, I have to click the desktop to move the focus to desktop, then press that key. Only in that way can my program receive the key event and take a screenshot. (the game itself provides an in-game camera to take screenshots, but the camera can't take screenshots of UI, inventory, etc. That's why I made this program.)

It's a easy fix to use global key hook, but if I use global key hook, my program will be prone to be identified as a malware (that steals password, for example.) by anti-malware softwares, meaning that I can't share it with other players. (After all, for players that are not good at computer, it is tiring to convince Windows Defender that my program is not malware.)

Is there any idea to catch the key event, but won't make my program identified as a malware?

Comment: Games routinely use raw input to read the keyboard, a good way to prevent users from cheating on multiplayer games.  That slurps input before the plumbing that implements RegisterHotKey() can see a keystroke.  Nothing you can do about that, you can't fix that by reading raw input yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a global key monitor by using [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input). To do so you need to set the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag in the [`RAWINPUTDEVICE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevice) structure passed into the [`RegisterRawInputDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices) call.